# How to change abstract in other language

Tags: babel, abstract, report, babel-french

I want to add the abstract in french after the one in english. `\selectlanguage{french}`, is only accepting the text inside the abstract and not the title which I want to change into **Résumé**.
Same for `\begin{otherlanguage}`. I tried also this solution https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12156

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand the question, this is straightforward:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
  In English.
\end{abstract}

\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
\begin{abstract}
  En français.
\end{abstract}
\end{otherlanguage}

Back to English.
\end{document}
```